# In tight binding 2d square lattice with two atoms basis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory, tight-binding

How can we get the equations inside the box, which represent hopping between p and d orbital? I mean why we consider only two neighbouring?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to PhysSE!

I didn't understand your first question, but I can answer the second one: these kinds of systems tend to have highly **localized** states - not in [Anderson sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson_localization) - such that its electronic clouds rarely pay visits to its neighbors'. The nearest-neighbor approximation can be done safely a lot of the time, because they usually are the most important in a material and suffice to explain its low-energy physics. Please, check Ashcroft and Mermin's Solid State Physics chapter 10 for an enlightening
exposition, or [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tight_binding) for a quick start.

Just out of curiosity: which book are these images from?

Comment: Thanks for responce. The book "Quantum theory of materials by Efthimios Kaxiras, John D. Joannopoulos.

Comment: Nice. Please upvote if my answer was helpful :)

Comment: Also, I'd love to help you with your first question if you could elaborate some more about it

Comment: The problem is that: I did not understand why the overlap between p and d orbitals give the results shown in the pic. As I understand for px and d orbitals we should have other terms at (-(a1+a2)), etc.  Why those terms are not included. Same thing for py and d-orbitals.

Comment: Add your own calculations so we can try to understand what's wrong